# How do I create a python setuptools entrypoint for package.__main__?

Tags: python, setuptools, entry-point

I want to have a directory structure like so:

```
package
package/__init__.py
package/__main__.py
setup.py
```

And use `package.__main__` as a entry point

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="package",
    version=0.1,
    ...
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["llmcli=llmcli"]},
)
```

Can I set [entrypoints](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is to refactor your `__main__.py` slightly, so that it calls a `main` function internally:

```py
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then you can add it as an entrypoint as `mymodule.__main__:main`.